# How to handle ERR_UNESCAPED_CHARACTERS error in Node.js using the 'https' package?

Tags: node.js, https

I am working on a project that requires making HTTP requests using the HTTP package. I currently use the `https.request()` method to make these requests.

However, I am running into an issue where I sometimes get an `ERR_UNESCAPED_CHARACTERS` error. I believe this error occurs when there are special characters in the URL that are not properly escaped.

how can I handle this error in the httpClient function itself? I want to be able to catch the error and log it, or perhaps even modify the URL before making the request.

Here is a simplified version of the code I am using:

```
const https = require('https');

function httpClient(url, options) {
  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    const req = https.request(url, options, (res) => {
      // handle response
    });

    req.on('error', (err) => {
      // handle error
        reject(error)
    });

    // write request data if necessary
    // req.write(data);

    req.end();
  });
}

// example usage
httpClient('https://example.com/path', { method: 'GET' })
  .then((res) => {
    // handle response
  })
  .catch((err) => {
    // handle error
  });
```

I am able to catch/handle standard erros like `ECONNREFUSED` in the httpClient function itself.

Any help on how to catch and handle the errors like `ERR_UNESCAPED_CHARACTERS` in the httpClient() function would be greatly appreciated. Thank you!